# bad superblock problem , unable to perform input output

Tags: 14.04, mount, hard-drive, smart

I have two hard drives in my laptop. Windows is installed on the 1TB hard disk and Ubuntu is installed in other. For some time I've been unable to open/access my Windows hard disk (I don't know what has happened).
Basically I want to retrieve the data and I don't want to reformat it, but any time I try to access the data it says:

```
cannot perform read operation
superblock is bad
```

[image: disk drive image]

[image: image while performing smart test]

After running `sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda` I get this error message:

```
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-4.15.0-112-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     ST1000LM035-1RK172
Serial Number:    WDE19T4G
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 09dcff080
Firmware Version: LVM1
User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 3b
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Wed Aug 19 05:32:30 2020 +0530
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

Read SMART Data failed: scsi error badly formed scsi parameters

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Status command failed: scsi error badly formed scsi parameters
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: UNKNOWN!
SMART Status, Attributes and Thresholds cannot be read.

Read SMART Log Directory failed: scsi error badly formed scsi parameters
Read SMART Error Log failed: scsi error badly formed scsi parameters
Read SMART Self-test Log failed: scsi error badly formed scsi parameters
Selective Self-tests/Logging not supported
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to ask ubuntu,

I would suggest, that you run a live distro and check both drives

```
sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda
sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdb
```

If you never used `smartctl` you can pipe the output in a file and add it here. If you can't read the superblock, you can use `e2fsck -p /dev/sdb1`. This repairs your superblock.
To keep sure that you don't destroy I would use `dd_rescue` before that part.